# External barcode scanner issue with flutter app

Tags: flutter, qr-code, barcode, flutter-qrcode

I built an simple App which scans your QR Code from an external Scanner and displays it on the screen. The QR code contain the Firebase user id which contains lower and uppercase letters. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJapf.jpg)I tried it on an emulator in windows while connecting the External scanner with usb and it worked fine. After running the app on a real device I realized that the QR Code which got scanned only returns the data in all lowercase letters. I don’t understand why. I then exited the flutter app and tried to see if it’s a scanner issue. Turns out anything other than flutter reads the QR code as it is. So it’s not a Scanner Problem. But it’s neither a flutter Problem because it worked on the Emulator so I can’t figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code doesn’t matter. It’s about the way the QR Code gets read inside the flutter app. Anyway I came up with the solution to pair every user id with a number Id and now my QR Codes contain numbers which solves the lowercase uppercase issue. I solved it thanks for trying to help.